# Is there a way to import generated structs in grpc.pb.go during protoc compilation?

Tags: go, grpc, proto, grpc-go

I am going to specify different out directories for generated structs from proto messages and generated interfaces from grpc service.

I achieve that with this two flags:

```
--go_out=internal/proto
--go-grpc_out=internal/grpc
```

After generating the internal/proto package is not imported in mymodel_grpc.pb.go file, but it would be very convenient if there is any flag to do that automatically during compilation.

I assume --go-grpc_opt flag could have such an option, but I couldn't find any.

Any experience with this kind of scenario is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to generate the protobuf messages in one package and the service bindings in another package.

Protobuf files include a `package` directive and this can be bound to `options` directives e.g. for Go(lang) using `go_package=`. The binding is 1:1; one package (and its messages|services) are bound to one e.g. Go package.

> **NOTE** Protobuf supports multiple languages too and so it must provide generic solutions that can be applied once (in Protobuf file) but used many (in each language's generated code).

So, I think your solution is to separate your messages and services into different packages (with different `options` and `go_package` specifications. Then, `protoc` can be guided to generated these to separate Golang packages.

Comment: Separating service and messages was good idea, additionally following this tips I've achieved what I wanted.
https://jbrandhorst.com/post/go-protobuf-tips/#use-the-go_package-option